# Context: Font database won't update after reloading fonts

Tags: luatex, context, debian, installing-fonts

I recently installed context on my laptop running Debian unstable. The version of context is 2017.05.015 and I installed it using apt.

My intention is to use system fonts in my generated documents, so i followed the instructions provided on the context website (http://wiki.contextgarden.net/simplefonts).

- I set an environment variable in my `.zshrc` (i use zsh):
  `export OSFONTDIR=~"/usr/share/fonts//;/usr/local/share/fonts//;~/.fonts//"`
- started a new shell
- updated the font database: `mtxrun --script fonts --reload --force`
- and finally ran a command to find the new entries: `mtxrun --script fonts --list --all`

Unfortunately I had no luck finding my system fonts located in `usr/share/fonts` etc in the database, although the output of the reload command shows that it found system fonts:

```
fonts           | names | identifying system font files with suffix 'AFM'
fonts           | names | globbing path '/home/julian/.fonts/**.AFM'
fonts           | names | globbing path '/home/julian/usr/share/fonts/**.AFM'
fonts           | names | globbing path '/usr/local/share/fonts/**.AFM'
fonts           | names | 43 system files identified, 0 skipped, 0 duplicates, 43 hash entries added, runtime 0.146 seconds
fonts           | names | 135 files rejected due to clashes
fonts           | names | 182 double lookups in 'mappings'
fonts           | names | 39 double lookups in 'fallbacks'
```

I get only the default fonts listed, such as Latin Modern, and can't use system fonts in my documents.

The system font i want to use is referenced like this:

```
\definefontfamily [mainface] [rm] [dejavusans]
\definefontfamily [mainface] [ss] [dejavusans]
\definefontfamily [mainface] [tt] [dejavusans]
\definefontfamily [mainface] [mm] [dejavusans]

\setupbodyfont[mainface]
```

Comment: What happens if you run `mtxrun --script fonts --list --pattern="Dejavu*" --all` (assuming you have dejavu fonts installed). It will also help if you add a minimal example showing how you are trying to use system fonts.

Comment: Don't use `simplefonts` and have a look at http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Fonts_in_LuaTex#How_LuaTeX_handles_system_fonts

Comment: @Aditya: I tried to run your suggested line, but any font i have installed in /usr/share/fonts, /usr/local/share/fonts and ~/.fonts will not show up at all. According to the results of the update command, i have 558 registered fonts. The list however is significantly shorter.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting solution:

All i did is removing the variable from .zshrc file and context seemed to use the default location, where it looks for font files. Maybe i did something wrong with it.

According to http://wiki.contextgarden.net/simplefonts:

> In Linux, the standard value is:
>
> OSFONTDIR= /usr/share/fonts//;$HOME/.fonts

Comment: Aside from your argument here (that I can't even get 'cause I'm no native english speaker). Is it just me, or you did set OSFONTDIR on your .zshrc file? I think it would be wiser if you set it as a global environment variable. For example, on my Gentoo box I created a file inside /etc/env.d/ and put in it the OSFONTDIR var with the values you'd want to set.